# Using Apache HttpComponents, how to authenticate to a proxy when tunneling HTTPS?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-proxy

- Using Apache HttpComponents 4.x or 5.x.
- I want to use an HTTP proxy that requires authentication.
- I want to connect to an HTTPS resource.

I can find documentation for authenticating to the proxy when connecting to HTTP resources (it's just a Proxy-Authentication header). I can find documentation for using an HTTPS proxy (uses CONNECT). However, normal proxy authentication does not work with HTTPS tunneling because the authentication header needs to be sent to the proxy after CONNECT, not as part of the normal request payload.

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, it is possible. HttpClient 4.x and 5.x supports proxy authentication by default. One just needs to correctly set up credentials for the proxy host

Comment: Can you point to a working example? When using HTTPS, HttpClient seems to try to send the Proxy-Authentication header along with the encrypted payload instead of along with the CONNECT. I've since switched to OkHttp and it works out of the box.

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java

Comment: That does not show an HTTPS destination. It breaks for HTTPS.